Magento ver. 2.4.5-p5: customer select grid view, when they change the category, it shouldn't go back to list view, it should stay with grid view
Magento ver. 2.4.5-p5 Listing page
can the website remember which layout the customer selected?
i.e. if they select grid view, when they change the category, it shouldn't go back to list view, it should stay with grid view.
